# Насколько безопасно передавать ключ доступа API через заголовки http?

Tags: php, http, api, rest, header

Пишу API, и тут возник вопрос как передавать ключ доступа, единственный вариант, как я понял, это http заголовки, передавать API заголовок 'API-KEY', но почему-то кажется это не сильно безопасным так как я считаю что могут перехватить ключ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTTPS вам в помощь,от бесплатного Let's Encrypt до копеечных ($3 в год) SSL от Sectigo

Comment: Это то имеется, я вот придумал схему передавать ключи в свзяке hash(APIKEY + signature) + APIKEY подпись хакер подделать не сможет, а при изменении любой буквы ключ будет невалиден, на сервере в базе можно хранить ключ и подпись

Comment: jwt токены уже изобрели.